# Why are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ tensors antisymmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

The book I'm reading (Nadir Jeevanjee (auth.)-An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists-Birkhäuser Basel (2015)) defined an antisymmetric tensor of type $(r,0)$ or $(0,r)$ as

> "one whose value changes sign under transposition of any two of its
>   arguments."

OK, I totally understand the definition, but now the book is telling me that all tensors of type $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$, are antisymmetric (the Wikipedia article about antisymmetric tensors agrees and even says they are trivial examples of an antisymmetric tensor). But I just don't get it! First, in the definition the book says "under transposition of any two of its arguments", but if the tensor is of type $(1,0)$, how can I transpose two arguments when I can just plug one? The only way, in my conception, for a tensor of type $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ to be antisymmetric is only if it is the $0$ tensor, since $0 = -0$.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Vectors and 1-forms are _vaccously_ (vaccous truth) skew. I mean, they only have one index, so you can't transpose any two of its arguments. In this case, the assertion comes true. My explanation is really bad but you can read about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). The idea is as follows: $T$ antysymmetric $\Leftrightarrow (\forall \mbox{ indices of } T\; i,j\;\; T_{\dots i\dots j\dots}=-T_{\dots j\dots i\dots})$ and since vectors only have 1 index the statement inside the brackes comes true..

Comment: I understand your point, but I still consider it very strange for them to be considered antisymmetric.

Comment: Another answer is: because you need it. But I don't like it too much, even it is true. It is convinitent for you to have your vector space inside the algebra.